# Is there a way in IntelliJ to prevent a commit with certain keywords?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I know my Intellij 12 notices if there are TODOs in the code I am about to commit and yells at me. I'd be curious if I could define some custom keywords or strings that, if are added in a commit, Intelij yells at you and, even better, just won't allow the commit if the string exists.

Anyone know? I doubt it  but it would be nice. This is an SVN repo for us, if that makes a difference.

Comment: related issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118450

Answer (score 5):

You can define more patterns in settings/TODO but it will work exactly like the existing patterns. Myself I try to move "local" changes to a different change-list to prevent accidental commits.